# Removing the security group rule if its open to 0.0.0.0/0 for RDP and SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, config, aws-security-group

I have configured an AWS Config rule that removes any security groups inbound rules if thats open to 0.0.0.0/0 for RDP and SSH. That works fine.

But It want that rule to be applied only to all private subnets and not public subnets. Is this possible?
Please help how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You COULD in the rule add resource identifiers (Seen under the Resources field), so you could add all the Security Group ID's in this field inside Config when editing the rule.  This is a bit tedious but it wold definitely achieve what you want to do.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but, this can be applied to the existing groups. What if new security groups are created, it has to auto remediate.. If they create in private subnet, it has to auto remediate, and not for public subnet.

Comment: Yeah I don't disagree it won't be that much help with newly created SG's, they will most likely need to be added in manually after creation or via some form of API call after being created... it's not ideal but would still serve the purpose and once added could be auto-remediated.

Comment: You are correct, but the account is accessible by many persons. So in that case, it wont be possible to add every newly created security groups to the list.. 

Is there a way to segregate the private and public subnets?